# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError even with setFetchSize

Tags: java, jdbc, memory-management, ojdbc

I am trying to load around 1 million worth of data in to result set, and write the result set to CSV string and then byte input stream. I bulk load the byte stream in to Greenplum Postges database with copy statement. While doing that, the code runs in to out of memory error.

This is the code:

```
import java.sql.*; 
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVWriter;
import java.io.*;
import org.postgresql.copy.CopyManager;
import org.postgresql.core.BaseConnection;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class WIDEtoGP { 
        public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
            try {
                /*String dbURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ortp14-scan)(PORT = 1521))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = WIORDP) (SRVR = DEDICATED)))";*/
                String dbURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = XXXXX)(PORT = 1521))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = XXXXX) (SRVR = DEDICATED)))";
                String strUserID = "XXXX";
                String strPassword = "XXXXX";             
                Connection myConnection=DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL,strUserID,strPassword);

                String readRecordSQL = "select id,name from account";    
                myConnection.setAutoCommit(false);
                PreparedStatement sqlStatement=myConnection.prepareStatement(readRecordSQL,ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
                System.out.print("Loading in to result set from Oracle: "+ Calendar.getInstance().getTime() + "\r\n");
                sqlStatement.setFetchSize(50000);
                ResultSet rs = sqlStatement.executeQuery(); 


                String dbURL1 = "jdbc:postgresql://xxxxx:5432/xxxx";
                String user = "xxxxxx";
                String pass = "xxxxxx";
                Connection conn2 = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL1, user, pass);
                Statement GPsqlStatement = conn2.createStatement();
                String readGPRecordSQL = "truncate java_test";
                GPsqlStatement.execute(readGPRecordSQL);

                rs.beforeFirst(); 

                while( rs.next() )

                {   

                StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
                CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(stringWriter);
                System.out.print("Start writing to CSV: "+ Calendar.getInstance().getTime() + "\r\n");
                csvWriter.writeAll(rs, true);
                System.out.print("Start writing to byte array input stream "+ Calendar.getInstance().getTime() + "\r\n");

                String orresult = stringWriter.toString();
                byte[] bytes = orresult.getBytes("UTF8");
                ByteArrayInputStream orinput = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes); 

                System.out.print("End time writing to byte array "+ Calendar.getInstance().getTime() + "\r\n");

                System.out.print("Load to Greenplum starts "+ Calendar.getInstance().getTime() + "\r\n");
                CopyManager copyManager = new CopyManager((BaseConnection) conn2);
                copyManager.copyIn("copy java_test from stdin csv header",orinput);
                System.out.print("Load to Greenplum ends "+ Calendar.getInstance().getTime() + "\r\n");

                csvWriter.close();
                }

                int size = 0;
                rs.last();
                size = rs.getRow();
                System.out.println("Row count of the load: " + size + "\r\n");

                rs.close();
                myConnection.close();
                conn2.close();
                System.out.print("Run time memory end: "+ Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()+ "\r\n");


            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.print("Error out time: "+ Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()+ "\r\n");
                System.out.println(e);
            }       
        }
    }
```

This is the exact error - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Any idea why is this happening? If it iterates 50k rows at once and closes all the objects that get used, I am pretty sure there is no memory shortage as the query has been able to load up to 500k rows at once.

I don't want to go through the SQL query route (instead of fetch size) for creating chunks as the tables keep getting updated every hour and if for some reason the run time of this process goes beyond one hour, it would end up screwing the data.

I also have to mention that this works up to 500000 rows without having any while block and directly moving the data. I had to introduce while block to make sure it runs in a loop while loading the data. It exactly fails after "start writing to CSV" comment.. gives memory error before even loading anything in to CSV object.

Any suggestions no how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not a good idea to write everything into a `String` *in memory*. You run out of memory. Stream the result to a file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But is there anyway to control the amount of data going in to the string? I thought with the above code, only 50k rows would be written to the string at once. It has seamlessly handled up to 500k rows a given time.

Comment: That is correct. 50k rows written at a time. Until you write **all** of the rows. Of course that assumes you can write **all** of the rows before running out of memory. You could buy more memory.

Comment: Thanks. How I do free up the memory after writing 50k rows? Given that it runs in a loop, wouldn't this csvWriter.close() - free up the csvwriter's memory after loading every 50k rows? I am keen on restricting the memory to be within defined limits, correct me if I am wrong, buying more memory might be more of a band aid. It is fine if the memory blows up for 50k rows, but that would be less unlikely for my case.

Comment: I don't think your approach is going to work, you would need to "chunk" the writes. Again, I would prefer to stream the results directly to the destination - add a buffer on that of your desired "chunk" size.

Comment: By destination, do you mean CSV or Postgres? It would be helpful if you could be little specific to my scenario.. this is my basic design: oracle result set -> CSV string (memory problem building this) -> Byte input stream -> Postgres

Comment: Doesn't really matter, if your destination is postres why are you going through all of those other steps to get there? Read a row, insert a row (using batches).

Comment: I just tried batch method (add batch, execute batch) by directly inserting result set from Oracle to Postgres. It is painfully slow. The above method including all steps end to end took less than a minute to insert 50k rows.. for the same volume,batch method was trying to slowly insert at a rate of 1000 rows per minute.. I killed after 10 minutes and it had barely inserted 10k rows. I believe copy is Postgres bulk loading technique, and I am not sure if there would be better options to load data that that. To leverage copy, above steps are essential.

Comment: How many elements did you add before you called executeBatch?